# assistance needed to get started with QUnit for jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I have written a custom plugin with jQuery 1.7.2.

I would like to unit test my JavaScript going forward and think this is the perfect start for such. I have looked at different JavaScript unit testing frameworks and I have decided to go with QUnit.

Being new to this I would like some assistance. Firstly with the understanding as to how I might go about unit testing a jquery plugin? And secondly how I may "stub" DOM elements to test the plugin?

Comment: Use Sinon for mocks , stubs , etc ... and QUnit for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Please try
 http://qunitjs.com/

This is worth reading.